# Cleaning semaphores in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, semaphore

I have a program that leaves some semaphores uncleaned and hence if i run it a couple of times, the program will seg fault. I used to use the following command in linux to clean them up.

```
ipcs -s | grep root |grep 666| cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs -I {} sudo ipcrm -s {}
```

but this doesnt work on mac. What command should i use to resolve this issue in mac osx?

Comment: Ideally I would advise that you fix the bugs causing the semaphores from being left open, but for the sake of answering this question, can you please provide output for 'ipcs -s' on the mac os x system?

Answer (score 1):

Some systems appear to add additional spaces between fields in the output, so you may need to specify the 3rd field instead:

```
ipcs -s | grep root |grep 666| cut -f3 -d' ' | xargs -I {} sudo ipcrm -s {}
```

I would consider this only a short-term fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue with some C code that I am working on so I wrote a simple C program to remove semaphores by name.

here is the code:

```
 #include <semaphore.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
         if (sem_unlink(argv[i]) != 0) {
             fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", argv[1]);
             perror("");
         }
     }
 }
```

once compiled you can call the program from a terminal with a list of semaphore names to remove like such:

```
$ ./semrm <name_1> <name_2> ... <name_n>
```

assuming the executable is named semrm

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on MacOS Ventura: I had to use an upper case `-S` for the key (third entry in the table)

```
ipcs -s | grep root | cut -f3 -d' ' | xargs -I {} sudo ipcrm -S {}
```

and the lower case `-s` with the id (second entry on the table)

```
ipcs -s | grep root | cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs -I {} sudo ipcrm -s {}
```

Replace `root` with another username or any other filtering.